# Genre of ADAM - Люба song (Ukrainian)

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists, blues

I really want to find similar music to this song by a Ukrainian artist, ADAM Люба:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fATwIZIx-I

What is the name of this music genre?

**EDIT 1:**

Lyrics in this song are about girl named Люба (Liuba) and probably about unrequited love or about regrets after finishing relations with this girl.

After receiving 2 answers I figured out that it's hard to identify a song using only one genre. I'll describe what I like in this song and what I'm looking for in similar music:

1. Song is slow, bluesy-like (probably), sounds old and I really like bass
2. Voice sounds high-pitched (non-native speaker here, using translator) - what I mean here is those "o-o-o-o" in the middle and the end of word.

Answer (score 1):

It could be classified as **Alternative** or **Indie Rock**, but I agree the sound is very specific and it could have it's own subgenre. Maybe you can find something with the keyword **Dark Country**.

For similar artist, I can suggest [*Timber Timbre*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timber_Timbre) songs:

- [*Black Water*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsuQUP1lfDA)
- [*Creep On Creepin On*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGBEgLXy6rU)
- [*Sewer Blues*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1h5ePI_cvHk)

Comment: Thank you for edit and response! Songs you've mentioned are good, but they aren't what I'm looking for. I didn't mentioned it in my original question and I did update it. I also did check *Dark Country*, *Alternative* and *Indie Rock* and last 2 are just too broad.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct was to go from the acoustic instruments and retro feel to get folk or Americana, and then modify that to make it slow and minor, yielding **[Gothic Americana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erukHUyLQcA&list=PLziJn12DyXtg5ZFc2qZ-SaFX5bAmqHqEE)** or **[Folk Noir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-wsKBd6_9I&list=PLCzwj-J3uk57zuKY_OfIJsJTUnJfj9hIP)**. But if what really interests you is the bass and high voice, that suggests modern **R&B**.  So my next suggestion would be **Alternative R&B**.  That gets you one of my own favorites, [Frank Ocean](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXiFHDfvn4A) (also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6Q6HYJOo2M)), as well as [James Blake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6p6PcFFUm5I&list=RDEMaxTlECeeEdamPeLzObFn5g)  and [other recent artists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sweE862aOGc&list=PL4QNnZJr8sRN78NkPkP0VSaFJ-IKPaO7V) with a similar sound.

It's not quite the right sensibility and beat, however, and features more modern instruments and percussion, so you could modify to **[Acoustic R&B](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wi5VCVX1cwc&list=PLBTKPYjiQdAbtuuOTt2-vD8VOqI-OUu2y)** for the instrumentation.  Conversely, you could try **Indie Blues Rock** for the beat and feel, which gets you [Hozier](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVjiKRfKpPI) and [the White Stripes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzgaOVWbZiU). Unfortunately that's generally more uptempo and hard rocking than what you're seeking.

In summary, although what you're looking for isn't necessarily an uncommon sound at all, it's hard to pinpoint it with any one genre.  Part of the problem is that, in America at least, falsetto and bass is a distinctively modern pop sound, but the backing track on your sample is much closer to older indie rock.  Your best bet, therefore, is to find an artist you like in one of the suggested genres and to listen through their catalog to find specific songs like the sample.

Comment: Thanks for edit and for detailed answer! I did check these 3 songs, I like them but again they aren't what I'm looking for - I didn't mention it in original question and I edited it with more details.

Comment: About genres: I think this song isn't very "folkish", and it isn't also very "dark". It's sad, but I don't think it's dark.